# Will paypal still accept the payments and redirects to suceess page? IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My question is very simple and no related to any kind of troubleshooting its just to get the information about the IPN

**Lets say:**

I have a system Paypal integrated activated IPN and working fine

someone tried to Price Jack a product and changed the price from 200$ to 2$

My IPN detected that and informed me about that issue (through mail as i set in my IPN).

My question is will paypal still process that payment and accept that 2$ and redirect user to my success page? or it will stop the processing the payment?

Ofcourse I have the proper handling of that and will not update the database

but question is will those 2 dollar will get processed in my paypal?

if yes is there any way to stop paypal from processing?

Comment: If this is a serious issue, you should use [encrypted buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/)

Comment: yep and besides that, you may also simply use hosted buttons (the only exposed code is an button ID), or turn to Express Checkout ( the API solution with payment tokenized) if you have already got a shopping cart system on your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there're multiple ways to protect your payment button code (price and other details) and also a very rare chance that an HTTPS payment request got "price-jacked" by a man-in-the-middle attack or malicious fraud activity, but still a valid question to be clarified.

In this case, the $2 will be processed just as a normal transaction to PayPal, and the asynchronous IPN will only be triggered by the event of payment completion. That's when your website backend will reconciliate and detect the "price-jack" by IPN callbacks, after the payment processing but not before.

Eventually, the transaction (of $2) that has taken place would be in sccope of fraud activity & dispute issue, and to be reported and handled by PayPal customer service

Comment: so what about those (2$) will it be mine without any services or where thy will go? How I will decide?

Comment: Apparently the right thing to do is communicate / refund or let the customer re-order from your site and pay the rest of the amount, it's nothing technical there but there's no money loss in this case

Comment: is there any safest way to stop process in case of fraud ?

Comment: Like in the comments of your question, use hosted button, encrypt the form code, or integrate with API solution, are all the right approach to protect your program in the first place